# Differentiate if an action is manual or automated in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I am implementing a functionality where when posting a journal entry, a validation error is raised if the related journal is locked and the operation is being done manually.

That is, the user clicked the accounting module to the accounting tab to journal entries submenu and then create.
This validation is only allowed depending on some rules attached to journals.

The way am doing this is by adding context `is_manual` to the journal entry action

```xml
<!-- Update the journal entry action -->
<record id="account.action_move_journal_line" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="context">
          {'default_move_type': 'entry', 'search_default_misc_filter':1, 'view_no_maturity': True, 'is_manual': True}
    </field>
</record>
```

Then from here I can check if this is true and perform the validation like this

```py
@api.multi
def post(self):
   res = super(AccountMove, self).post()

   for rec in self:
      if self._context.get('is_manual'):
         user = self.env.user
         approval_users = rec.journal_id.rule_id.user_ids.mapped('user_id.id')
         if rec.journal_id.requires_approval and user.id not in approval_users:
            raise UserError(_("You're not allowed to approve this document with this 
                   Journal!"))

   return res
```

The problem I am having is that some records being created using APIs are failing to post which can only be if the context check is failing.
My question is, **is there a better way of achieving the same?**

The above implementation is for **odoo v11**.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you instead restrict access to the view element(s) if the user does not have permission? This would allow you to avoid a Python validation check altogether by preventing unauthorized users from clicking what they're not supposed to.

Comment: That would be the case, but the user is allowed to create journal entries and post with other non restricted journals

Comment: Could you use a [record rule](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/security.html#record-rules) to enforce the restriction? Access rights allow defining CRUD rules per model. Record Rules allow refining the CRUD rules to restrict/authorize only records matching a particular domain.

Comment: Yes that would be the way if these users were not allowed to ever create documents that are restricted. But the restriction works for a manual process only, that is they are allowed to create customer invoices, that will automatically create a journal entry

Comment: This method actually works, just that it was being interfered with by an external application. The solution am going with is creating a group that overrides these rules and assigning the API users to that group.